# Angularjs Update Scope variable within setTimeout not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout

I have an array that will contain many commands that I send to an external application.

```
$scope.commandLog = [{"id":"1", "time":"12.02.2015 20:05:20.606","command":"cmd1", "status":"idle"},
                    {"id":"2", "time":"12.02.2015 20:05:20.606","command":"cmd2", "status":"idle"},
                    {"id":"3", "time":"12.02.2015 20:05:20.606","command":"cmd3", "status":"idle"},
                    {"id":"4", "time":"12.02.2015 20:05:44.162","command":"cmd4", "status":"idle"},
                    {"id":"5", "time":"12.02.2015 20:05:44.162","command":"cmd5", "status":"success"},
                    {"id":"6", "time":"12.02.2015 20:05:44.162","command":"cmd6", "status":"idle"},
                    {"id":"7", "time":"13.02.2015 12:05:52.181","command":"cmd7", "status":"idle"},
                    {"id":"8", "time":"13.02.2015 12:05:52.181","command":"cmd8", "status":"idle"}]
```

I am looping over the array, and set a delay before the next loop begins. This is working fine.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.commandLog.length; i++)
    {

        (function(index) {
            setTimeout(function() {

               // DO STUFF HERE

            }, i * 2000);
        })(i);

    }
```

I want to change the status of the object at the current array index like so:

```
$scope.commandLog[index].status = 'active';
```

I have a table that shows the commands and their status

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>Command</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="cmd in commandLog" ng-class="cmd.status" ng-attr-id="{{ 'command-' + cmd.id }}">
      <td>{{cmd.time}}</td>
      <td>  <span class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="sendCommand(cmd.command)"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span></td>
      <td>{{cmd.command}}</td>
      <td>{{cmd.status}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that the cell `<td>{{cmd.status}}</td>`is not updating to "active" even though when I write the object to the console, I do see that the status is set to active.

If I run the code without the delay, just the for loop, it does work.

JSFiddle with the complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/8ezh6Ljh/1/

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain what I am doing wrong.
TIA

Comment: use the [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service instead of the traditional `setTimeout`.

Comment: If you change object in collection, you need use Watch:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch  
or
WatchCollection: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection 

depends of your need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code inside the `setTimeout` function is running outside of angular world.

To let angular know about changes you made to your data, either call `$scope.$apply()` or use the `$timeout` service.

Check this [plunker](https://jsfiddle.net/7fk5w0c2/)